# Using orientDB ETL json transform

Tags: etl, orientdb

does anyone have examples of orientDB etl transformers with multiple transforms or something that can create class identifiers on the fly, so for example, if you want to create organization entities and the id could be a hash from the organization name , essentially if the json we are importing is not exactly the schema we want in the destination

Answer (score 0):

What about using block `code` in your ETL configuration file? You can use it in the `begin` phase, so you could transform id column in your .csv input file. It is not an ideal solution I agree.

- see the [Block documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/orientdb-etl.wiki/Block.html)